# ie conditional html statement

Tags: html, css

I'm using the conditional statement here to add i.e. browsers css styles

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

If I test in emulators this conditional statement doesn't seem to work, the html tag doesn't have the 'lt-ie9' class.

If I test in products like browserstack the conditional statement seems to work and I can see the text thats is shown with the class .lt-ie9

Is the conditional html tag correct? Should I not trust the emulators

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>  
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

            <!--jQuery-->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!--css-->
            <style type="text/css">

          .test{
            color: red;
            display: none;
            font-size: 2em;
          }

          .lt-ie9 .test{
            display: block;
          }

            </style>


            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->

            <title>Title of the document</title>
        </head>

    <body>

      <div class="test">IE8</div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the emulators in question, there's no way for us to know. Your best course of action in debugging is to copy down that code into the body and replace the html tags with something visible:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> IE, Less than 7<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    IE 7 <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    IE 8 <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> IE 9+ or not-IE <!--<![endif]-->
```